# Проставленные метки через ПК браузер в конструкторе карт вывести на телефон в Яндекс карты

Tags: конструктор, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

в общем - раскидываю листовки по парадным, столкнулся с тем что не удобно каждый раз вбивать новый адрес и искать дом, теряется очень много времени. Наткнулся на конструктор карт, метки расставил, экспортировал разные типы файла но именно к яндекс картам они не подходят. Может есть вариант с синхронизацией яндекс аккаунта в ПК и телефоне(андроид), в идеале удобнее такой алгоритм - проставил метки в браузере ПК и экспортировал в телефон. Подскажите пожалуйста вариант решения. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если сценарий использования меток - только навигация в мобильных Яндекс.Картах, то проще создавать закладки в браузерных Яндекс.Картах. Они всегда будут доступны в мобильном приложении. Там есть также возможность создавать папки с закладками, чтобы делать отдельные списки объектов.